# How often does a betting-house's odds change for a given event 1) before and 2) during the event?

Tags: statistics, betting

I understand that this is VERY dependent on the specific sporting event, but I was hoping to find some representative averages and ranges ... beyond somewhere between a few times-per-day *before* the event and few times-per-minute *during* the event.

It also would be interesting to analyze the odds-change-frequency differences...

1. between various sports (basketball vs football vs soccer, etc),
2. between different levels within a sport (pros vs college), and
3. varying competitiveness within the game (even-ish odds vs longshot/heavy-favorite).

Comment: Spread-betting odds in Cricket change after every ball. That could be 3000 times during the match, although towards the end betting stops.

Comment: Wow ... one could wonder how the bookies keep track.

Comment: @JimfromBoston Keep track of what?

Answer (score 2):

I'll speak for soccer as I have some experience of delving into the stats and odds for that sport. On Betting Exchanges the odds can be changing by the second during a game, that is a good place to get visibility of the changes. Websites like https://www.oddsportal.com/ are good places to go and see what the markets were doing before games started, it has info on all the major sports. For stats about odds during games it is harder to find the odds info and crucially the reasons for those changes in odds, beyond goals, red cards etc.

If a game is televised then that can affect the frequency of the odds change but for the major leagues in any sport that is increasingly becoming a null point because every game pretty much is televised.

Odds before a game can change by up to 10% but they tend to go in one direction ([see here](https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/league-one/burton-cambridge-utd-YTdJ5Juc/), it is quite common for a team to be given odds of 45% chance of winning to go to 55% chance of winning at kick off. It is pretty rare for the team to go from 45 to 55 and then back to 45 before kick off.

Changing sports, for the upcoming Superbowl, taken from oddsportal, below are the odds for the Los Angeles Rams from bet365. On the 31st Jan the bookie said they had a 65% chance of winning (100/1.54), now on the 13th Feb bet365 are saying they have a 68% chance of winning. I am not trying to make any point with that, just that that is the kind of info you'll find.

[image]